# xpath not contains A and B

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

How can I add 
`not(contains(.,'facebook')`, `not(contains(.,'twitter')` to my xpath.

```
sites = selector.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a[@href[not(contains(.,'google')   )]]/@href")
```

I want to find a url without `google`,`facebook`,and`twitter` in it
Please help me ,thank you

Comment: You need to be more careful to express your requirements unambiguously. I suspect you want a url without google, twitter, OR facebook in it: that is, any one of the three disqualifies the URL, whereas the way you have written it, it is only disqualified if all three are present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join conditions with `and`:

```
//h3[@class='r']/a[not(contains(@href,'google')) and not(contains(@href,'facebook')) and not(contains(@href,'twitter'))]/@href")
```

Or, use [`.re()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) available on the `Selector` instance:

```
selector.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a/@href").re('^(?!.*(google|facebook|twitter)).*$')
```

Also, you can use [`re:test()` function](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions):

```
selector.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a[not(re:test(@href, '(google|facebook|twitter)'))]/@href")
```