# XPath returns empty list. Why is it ignoring targeted div element?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, html-parsing

I'm a newbee to XPath and Scrapy. I'm trying to target a node which does not have a unique class (i.e. `class="pubBody"`).

Already tried: 
[xpath not contains A and B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163626/xpath-not-contains-a-and-b)

This should be a simple task but XPath just misses the second item. I am doing this from the scrapy shell. On the command prompt:

scrapy shell "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/00221694/"

I am looking for the second div:

```
<div id="issueListHeader" class="pubBody">...< /div>

<div class="pubBody">... < /div>
```

I can only get the first but not the second. The best answers to similar questions suggested trying something like:

```
hxs.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"pubBody") and not(contains(@id,"issueListHeader"))]')
```

but this returns an empty list for some reason. Any help please? Must be missing something silly, I've tried this for days!

Other details:

Once in the scrapy shell:

```
import scrapy

xs = scrapy.Selector(response)

hxs.xpath('//div[@class="pubBody"]')
```

Which works only for the first div element:

```
[<Selector xpath='//div[@class="pubBody"]' data='<div id="issueListHeader" class="pubBody'>]
```

For the failed second div element I've also tried:

```
hxs.xpath('//div[@class="pubBody" and not(@id="issueListHeader")]').extract_first()

hxs.xpath('//div[starts-with(@class, "pubBody") and not(re:test(@id, "issueListHeader"))]')
```

Also directly copied the XPath from Chrome, but also returns '[]':

```
hxs.xpath('//*[@id="issueList"]/div/form/div[2]')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447738/beautifulsoup-html5lib-module-object-has-no-attribute-base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the *HTML is very far from being well-formed on this page*. To demonstrate, see how the same exact CSS selector is producing 0 results with Scrapy and producing 94 in [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html5lib')  # note: "html5lib" has to be installed

In [3]: len(soup.select(".article h4 a"))
Out[3]: 94

In [4]: len(response.css(".article h4 a"))
Out[4]: 0
```

Same goes for the `pubBody` element you are trying to locate:

```
In [6]: len(response.css(".pubBody"))
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: len(soup.select(".pubBody"))
Out[7]: 2
```

So, try hooking up `BeautifulSoup` to fix/clean up the HTML - ideally through a [middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#writing-your-own-downloader-middleware).

---

I've created a simple [`scrapy_beautifulsoup` middleware](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-beautifulsoup) to easily hook up into the project:

- install it via pip:

  ```
  pip install scrapy-beautifulsoup
  ```
- configure the middleware in `settings.py`:

  ```
  DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
      'scrapy_beautifulsoup.middleware.BeautifulSoupMiddleware': 543
  }
  BEAUTIFULSOUP_PARSER = "html5lib"
  ```

Profit.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe ! Your middleware did the job!! PS. I also had an issue with not having beautiful soup updated, after upgrading from 4.4.1 to 4.5.1 all worked ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447738/beautifulsoup-html5lib-module-object-has-no-attribute-base )  Side note: On your GitHub "readme" chunk you separate the settings.py changes into two code chunks. Having the two setting changes in one chunk (like you have in this answer) was easier to understand for a newbee! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the source for the page you'r trying to parse (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/00221694/) is not valid XML due to the `<link ...>` nodes/elements/tags not having closing tags.  There may be other problems, but those are the first ones I found.

I'm rusty on Javascript, but you may try navigating down the DOM down to a lower level in the page (ie. body or some other node closer to the elements you're trying to target) and then perform the XPath from that level.

**UPDATE:** I just tried removing the `<head>` of the document and passing it through an XML parser and it still breaks on sever `<input>` nodes that are not closed.  Unless I'm forgetting some special JavaScript XML/XPath rules methods that dismiss closing tags I suspect you might be better suited to use something like JQuery to find the elements you're looking for.