# Path with multiple "and contains"

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the URLs contained in these:

```
<a href="tel:(352) 376-4090" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" class="SK-FuGf">

<a rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" class="SK-FuGf" href="http://www.bodytechtattoo.com">

<a rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" class="SK-FuGf" href="https://www.instagram.com/bodytech_piercings">
```

They all share the same class. Let's say I want to scrape only the website link (the second one).

Can you help me understand why the following Path is not working for that?

```
//a[@class="SK-FuGf" and not(contains(@href, “instagram.com")) and not(contains(@href, "tel:"))]/@href
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xpath not contains A and B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163626/xpath-not-contains-a-and-b)

Comment: May be because in that xpath before the word "instagram" there's a typographical double quotation mark. Replace that and try again. If it doesn't work, please include in your question the html so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I found the culprit. The stupid quotes! They must be "" and not “