# Excluding tags with links using Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I want to exclude all elements that contain links, using xpath

```
<p/>...</p>
<p/>...</p>
....
<p/>
<strong/>
<a href="https://exapmle.com" rel="nofollow">Link</a>
 </strong>
</p>
```

I need to parse all tags excluding the last one which contains href

found some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163626/xpath-not-contains-a-and-b)
Tried `p[not(contains(@href,'example'))]`, but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Please let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: I think you could try the solution provided in my answer and this might be what you needed :)

Answer (score 3):

This XPath will give you all the `p` nodes not containing `a` child containing `href` attribute:

```py
"//p[not(.//a[@href])]"
```

Also since you are using Selenium - XPath 2.0 is not relevant here since Selenium supports Xpath 1.0 only

Answer (score 1):

**I think you want this:**

```
//a[@href]/ancestor::p[1]
```

**When the above XPath expression is evaluated on this XML document**:

```
<html>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2
        <p>23
            <a href="xxx">XXX</a>
        </p>
    </p>
    <p>3
        <p>34
            <a href="yyy">YYY</a>
        </p>
    </p>
    <p>4
        <p>45

        </p>
    </p>
</html>
```

**exactly the wanted (to be excluded) `<p>`  elements are selected**:

```
<p>23
          <a href="xxx">XXX</a>
</p>
<p>34
          <a href="yyy">YYY</a>
</p>
```

**In case you need all elements  excluding the above, use:**

```
//*[count(. | //a[@href]/ancestor::p[1]) 
   > 
    count(//a[@href]/ancestor::p[1])
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one?

```
//p[descendant::a[not(contains(@href,'example'))]]
```

You are getting all the `p` elements which their `a` childs do not contain the `href` property with value `example`

Also this one can be valid for what you want:

```
//p[.//a[not(contains(@href,'example'))]]
```

Comment: it works, but in previous tags <p> only text without any <a> and I need them. 
So, I need to exclude <p> tags with <a> which contain 'example'. Is there any solution?
Thanks for your help.